# How to create and use 1k wallet signers on hardhat to test smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I am gonna write smart contracts test on hardhat.
By default, hardhat provides 20 signers with enough amount of ETH on it.
But for my contracts, I will need 1000 signers and each signer should have some eth on it.
How can I achieve this? I can create any amount of random wallets using ethers but am not sure how to send ether and use that random wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const signer = await ethers.getImpersonatedSigner(ethers.Wallet.createRandom().address);
```

Answer (score 0):

In hardhat.config.js[ts], you could config accounts.
Like this:

```
module.exports = {
 ...
 networks: {
   hardhat: {
      accounts: [
         privateKey0, 
         privateKey1, 
         privateKey2, 
         ...
      ]
   }
 }
 ...
}
```

how to send ether:
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/send-token-etherjs/